# Python large size array and high time cost

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, performance, window-functions

I want to create an `np.ndarray` as an input for a machine learning model:

```
array_X = np.array([list(w.values) for w in df[['close', 'volume']].rolling(window=20)][19:-1])
```

It is the standard way in time series, where we use a window of past values as an input to predict the future value. The shape of array is `2 * 20 * 20000000`. It will cost a lot of time to build such array and sometime there will be an error that the memory consumed by the array is too large.

Is there any way to improve the above (time cost and memory error)?

Comment: Input of size 40 * 20_000_000 samples is by no means "standard way in time series". I guess what you do you are trying to make whole dataset fit into RAM. Instead load input in batches of 32-128 sample or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original code gives me an error because of a dimension mismatch for the first few entries in the array, which are too short because the window isn't full yet, so I changed it to discard the first values:

```
def rolling_approach(df, window_size=3):
    return np.array(
        [w.values for w in df[["close", "volume"]].rolling(window=window_size)][
            window_size - 1 :
        ]
    )
```

[`pd.DataFrame.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) can be extremely slow for these kinds of operations. [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) is very efficient in `pandas`  Here's an example for `window_size=3` written out:

```
pd.concat(
            [
                df[["close", "volume"]].shift().shift(),
                df[["close", "volume"]].shift(),
                df[["close", "volume"]],
            ],
            axis=1,
        )
        .values[2:, :]
        .reshape(-1, 3, 2)
    )
```

We stack the shifts and then reshape the values.

Generalized to a variable `window_size` we get:

```
def shift_approach(df, window_size=3):
    shifted_df = pd.concat(
        [df[["close", "volume"]].shift(i) for i in range(window_size - 1, -1, -1)],
        axis=1,
    )
    reshaped_array = shifted_df.values[window_size - 1 :, :].reshape(-1, window_size, 2)
    return reshaped_array
```

`shift` outperforms the `rolling` operation by almost two orders of magnitude:

[image]

And it scales somewhat well into hundreds of millions of rows on my MacBook:
[image]

```
def setup(N):
    np.random.seed(42)
    close_values = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=N)
    volume_values = np.random.randint(100, 1000, size=N)
    df = pd.DataFrame({"close": close_values, "volume": volume_values})
    return [df, 10]


approaches = [rolling_approach, shift_approach]
# Show correctness
for approach in approaches[1:]:
    data = setup(10)
    assert np.isclose(approach(*data), approaches[0](*data)).all()

run_performance_comparison(
    approaches,
    [
        1000,
        3000,
        5000,
        10000,
        30000,
        100_000,
        300_000,
        500_000,
        1_000_000,
        3_000_000,
        5_000_000,
        10_000_000,
    ],
    setup=setup,
    title="Performance Comparison",
    number_of_repetitions=2,
)
```

Profiling code:

```
import timeit
from functools import partial

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from typing import List, Dict, Callable

from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def data_provider(data_size, setup=lambda N: N, teardown=lambda: None):
    data = setup(data_size)
    yield data
    teardown()


def run_performance_comparison(approaches: List[Callable],
                               data_size: List[int],
                               setup=lambda N: N,
                               teardown=lambda: None,
                               number_of_repetitions=5, title='Performance Comparison', data_name='N'):
    approach_times: Dict[Callable, List[float]] = {approach: [] for approach in approaches}
    for N in data_size:
        with data_provider(N, setup, teardown) as data:
            for approach in approaches:
                function = partial(approach, *data)
                approach_time = min(timeit.Timer(function).repeat(repeat=number_of_repetitions, number=2))
                approach_times[approach].append(approach_time)

    for approach in approaches:
        plt.plot(data_size, approach_times[approach], label=approach.__name__)
    plt.yscale('log')
    plt.xscale('log')

    plt.xlabel(data_name)
    plt.ylabel('Execution Time (seconds)')
    plt.title(title)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: I tried that your solution is much fast! So the left question is that the array with large size seems has a memory error like MemoryError: Unable to allocate 84.4 MiB for an array with shape (11056593,)

Comment: @user6703592 maybe use np.float32 (or even smaller data types if possible).

Comment: @dankal444 thing is very strange, sometime the same array generated from df.values is ok, but array build from other way like for loop: array_X = [] for i in range(): array_X.append()... will have the memory error. Is it related to some overflow of the temporary cache?

Comment: profiling memory can be extremely tricky. it depends on your platform, the rest of your program and what python feels like doing at any specific point. I scaled the solution to a few hundred million rows and didn't get a OOM error on my macbook. Maybe sprinkle a few `gc.collect()` calls in your program? Probably does nothing but you never know.

Comment: I asked a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76965427/memory-exposed-for-muti-threads-of-applying-a-custimized-funtion-on-the-rolling, do you have some idea?