# memory exposed for muti-threads of applying a custimized funtion on the rolling window

Tags: python, dataframe, multithreading

The number of rows of dataframe `df` is very large. Below answer: [Python large size array and high time cost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76668997/python-large-size-array-and-high-time-cost/76670339#76670339), is a very efficient way to build the `rolling window` of column `a`

```
df['a'].rolling(window=window)
```

Now I want to use multi-thread function to run a custimized funtion `f` on the rolling window:

```
df['label'] = df['a'].rolling(window=window).apply(lambda x: f(x))
```

I used the similar way:

```
shifted_df = pd.concat(
    [df['a'].shift(i) for i in range(window-1, -1, -1)], axis=1)
def fun_df(i, shifted_df, f):
    value = f(shifted_df.iloc[i].values)
    df_res = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['label'])
    df_res.loc[shifted_df.index[i], 'label'] = value
    del value, i
    return df_res
```

Namely run each row as a thread pallerally. Then I can see the memory in `htop` exposed immediately. I guess maybe the large dataframe `shifted_df` is copied too many times. Is there any efficient way to achieve `.apply(lambda x: f(x))`?